# Bad Regex in Django? DetailView, ListView, and blog construction

Tags: python, regex, django, detailview

I'm hoping this is just an issue of my poor regex understanding.
I'm attempting to use the exact code on [Django 1.9's generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/) to build a blog and personal site, and, down to the testing, here's where I run into trouble:

```
def test_post_page(self):
    post = PostModelFactory()
    first_post = Post.objects.all()[0]
    post_url = first_post.get_absolute_url()

    print(post_url)

    response = self.client.get(post_url, follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

So, through that print statement, I determined `models.Post.get_absolute_url()` was returning my homepage URL. Here's models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40,unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "%s/" % (self.slug)
```

Should it come up, I copied down what the generic views documentation has, so my Detailview in `/blog/urls.py`is as follows:

```
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

Same of `views.py`:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

As far as I can tell, my get_absolute_url() function is simply not doing what I think it's doing, let alone what the regex in urls.py expects it to do.

Also:  Is there anyone who can fully explain how slugfield works? I know it's a keyword generator to create a url, but I'm not sure how it works (or doesn't, as in this example). 
Then, finally, in both a tutorial that I'm quasi-following alongside the documentation, and the documentation, itself, I'm not fully understanding where the variable names in templates are coming from (my understanding is that the request hit's the URL, which generates the data from views.py). The "ListView" object in the template shares the model name, "post" (or "article" in the documentation), where its pageview at the bottom is accessed simply through "page_obj", and the "DetailView" object is simply called "object". I also may be having a problem with paginating my ListView, ( which is identical to the documentation example, but with the extra line `paginate_by = 2` right above `get_context_data`.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I've included PostModelFactory:

```
class PostModelFactory(DjangoModelFactory):


   class Meta:
        model = Post()
        django_get_or_create = (
            'title',
            'subtitle',
            'text',
            'pub_date',
        )

    title = 'This is a test.'
    subtitle = 'This is only a test.'
    text = 'Madness? This is Sparta.'
    pub_date = timezone.now()

    def __init__(self):
        self.save()
```

Edit: The issue turned out to be the lack of a slug in the PostModelFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use `reverse` in `get_absolute_url`, instead of hardcoding it.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[self.slug])
```

If you do hardcode the URL, it should contain a leading slash.

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%s/" % (self.slug)
```

If `first_post.get_absolute_url` is returning the homepage url with your current `get_absolute_url`, that suggests that the slug is an empty string.

Comment: Hold up - I'm a bit confused. Did you move `def get_absolute_url(self):` into the `PostDetailView` class in `views.py`?  That's a bit confusing.

Also, I began with the leading slash, but the `print` statement gave me "//" back, so, when I removed the leading slash, I got "/" back.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, the `get_absolute_url` method belongs on the `Post` model.

Comment: If you're getting `"//"` from printing the absolute url, check whether your `slug` field is getting populated or not. Generally you have to create it yourself, it's not an auto field like your `pub_date` field or PK. At least at the model level, there are some admin options to have the admin set it based on other fields IIRC.

Comment: If the print statement shows `//`, that means that the slug is the empty string `''`. Usually, the slug is a simplified version of the title, suitable for the URL. For example, if the title is `My first blog post`, then the slug might be `my-first-blog-post`. It's up to you to set the slugs for your models, they are not generated automatically when the post is created. You might find the [`prepopulated_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) model admin option useful.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
@Alasdair - The reverse function seems to not be working for `'post-detail'`, but it does seem to be using the regex:

Error: `django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$']`


@PeterDeGlopper - I haven't logged into admin to confirm (since tests won't save the data), but above error suggests it's not being populated.
I tried setting it in test with `post.slug = 'this-is-a-post'`, but test still returns "//".

Comment: That traceback looks like it's not passing the slug to `reverse` at all, if it were `arguments` wouldn't be the empty tuple. Check for typos maybe? The answer's call looks right to me.

Comment: I haven't used factory boy, but it looks like you need to include something like `slug = 'this-is-a-test'` in your `PostModelFactory`. As Peter says, your traceback does not match my answer.

Comment: @Alasdair - That looks like it was it. Passing tests, so far! Thanks!

Now let's hope it _actually works_.

Comment: Well, I'm having issues understanding how ListView generates url's for pagination, but consider the main issue in this topic solved.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, it would be better to ask a new question.

Comment: @Alasdair
Oddly enough, the title might be almost exactly the same.